# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Data Grip

Tags: mysql, jdbc, datagrip

I'm new to SQL (I don't know anything). I tried using DataGrip as it seems like a good tool. However, when I created a new Data Source and made it MySQL, when I tried running it it gave me:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.
```

When I pressed the *Test Connection* it gave me an error too.[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You don't have MySQL running on port 3306 on localhost, or your firewall doesn't allow you to connect.

Comment: So what do I change it too?

Comment: Do you have MySQL installed and is it running?

Comment: No, I thought I didn't need to install it as DataGrip auto-complete/syntax highlighting and other tools seem to be working.

Comment: Datagrip is an IDE for databases, it doesn't provide the database itself (except for JDBC drivers that provide an embedded database, like HSQLDB, Apache Derby and others). The auto-complete / syntax highlighting is a feature of Datagrip, not of the database server. If you want to use MySQL, you will need to install MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for that! Just downloaded MySQL, and it's working.